# Nested asynchronous tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, task-parallel-library

I would like to know if it's possible to improve this code for better performance. I'm new to the whole async thing on the serverside, so please bear with me here:

```
con.GetGame(id, game => {

    foreach(Player p in game.Team1)
    {
        p.SomeExtraDetails = GetPlayerDetails(p.Id);
    }

    // I would like the player data to be set on all players
    // before ending up here
});

private PlayerDetails GetPlayerDetails(double playerId)
{
    var task = con.GetPlayer(playerId);

    PlayerDetails ret = null;

    Task continuation = task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        ret = t.Result;
    });

    continuation.Wait();

    return ret;
}
```

If I got it right, `continuation.Wait();` blocks the main thread.

Is there any way to make the tasks run simultaneously?

Comment: Can you use C# 5.0? Also, why do some of your methods use continuations and some `Task`s? I think it would be better if you were consistent.

Comment: @svick I'm using a VS2012, but I believe it's .NET 4.5 atm.

Comment: @Johan It's not a typo - it's C# 5 (language) and .NET 4.5 (framework) ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally, you'd make these operations asynchronous all the way down:

```
private Task<PlayerDetails> GetPlayerDetailsAsync(double playerId)
{
    return con.GetPlayer(playerId);
}

con.GetGame(id, game => {
    var tasks = game.Team1
                    .Select(p => new { Player=p, Details=GetPlayerDetailsAsync(p.Id)})
                    .ToList(); // Force all tasks to start...

    foreach(var t in tasks)
    {
        t.Player.SomeExtraDetails = await t.Details;
    }

    // all player data is now set on all players
});
```

If that isn't an option (ie: you're not using VS 2012), you could simplify your code to:

```
// This is a more efficient version of your existing code
private PlayerDetails GetPlayerDetails(double playerId)
{
    var task = con.GetPlayer(playerId);
    return task.Result;
}

con.GetGame(id, game => {
    // This will run all at once, but block until they're done
    Parallel.ForEach(game.Team1, p =>
    {
        p.SomeExtraDetails = GetPlayerDetails(p.Id);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer. I tried your last example, but I got an exception on `return task.Result`: `The Write method cannot be called when another write operation is pending."`

Comment: @Johan It sounds like your GetPlayer method isn't thread safe ;)

Comment: @Johan Difficult to tell without knowing what's going on - the first option above, btw, would be far superior if you can get it to work (no blocking at all)

Comment: Ok, I've tried the first one. The await keyword gets highlighted with `The 'await' operator can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the 'async' modifier`

Comment: @Johan You need to make your method an async method.

Comment: Yeah, I tried `private async Task<...`, still the same error though.

Comment: @Johan It's the `con.GetGame(id, async (game) => {` - Not sure of the context, though - it may not be easy to modify that to handle Task<T> propertly

Comment: I'll dig deeper in to this. I really appreciate your help Reed, thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

consider using [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx) in your GetGame page instead of Task.ContinueWith

Comment: Would you mind showing me how it's implemented in my example?

Comment: @Johan Consider other answers and try to avoid copy-paste programming

Comment: @IlyaBursov This is not about copy-paste programming. This is about understand what exactly you meant and how would you actually use `Parallel.ForEach()`.

Comment: copy-pasting from answer above ` Parallel.ForEach(game.Team1, p =>
    {
        p.SomeExtraDetails = GetPlayerDetails(p.Id);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution without LINQ (although I like Reed Copsey's solution). However, *beware that*, as pointed out in the comments, this solution introduces an overhead by encapsulating the call to `GetPlayerDetailsAsync()` inside Tasks created by `Task.Run()`.

Requires .NET 4.5 and C# 5.

```
con.GetGame(id, game => {

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach(Player p in game.Team1)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => p.SomeExtraDetails = await GetPlayerDetailsAsync(p.Id)));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
});

private Task<PlayerDetails> GetPlayerDetailsAsync(double playerId)
{
    return con.GetPlayerAsync(playerId);
});
```

Further, in order to catch up on the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) with .NET 4.5 I highly recommend reading: [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) - by Stephen Toub, Microsoft.

Comment: This works and looks nice, but uses the ThreadPool unnecessarily...  Task.Run will rely on TP threads to run the tasks, where my version avoids that

Comment: @ReedCopsey I totally agree on that. I should have pointed that out while I was writing the answer. However, I have updated my answer now so it is clear that this alternative implementation introduces an overhead in regards to multiple invocations of `Task.Run()`.